# Finding the matrix of a relation $R$ on $X$

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, relations

> Given the relation:
>
> $$    
> R = \{(x, y)|x < y\}
> $$
>   and the ordering of $x$ is $\{ 1,2,3 \}.$
>   How to find the matrix of this relation?

I honestly cannot understand the question.
Any tips to solve this problem?

DISC 101, Relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathcal{R}$ is a relation between $X$ and $Y$ and $x_1, ..., x_m$ is an ordering of the elements of $X$ and $y_1, ..., y_n$ is an ordering of the elements of $Y$, then the matrix $M$ of $\mathcal{R}$ is a $m \times n$ matrix such that $m_{i,j} = 1$ if $x_i \mathcal{R} y_j$ and $0$ otherwise.

In your example, $X = Y = \{1,2,3\}$ and the ordering is $1, 2, 3$.
$M$ is therefore a $3 \times 3$ matrix, such that $m_{i,j} = 1$ if $i < j$ and $0$ otherwise.
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$